# C# parameter passing List<T>

Tags: c#, parameters

I have this code on C# clearing text textboxes in method way:

```
public void clearThis(List<TextBox> txtbox){
    foreach (TextBox nTxtbox in txtbox){
        nTxtbox.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Need help please, how can pass my textboxes on:

```
clearThis(Arrays.asList(textbox1,textbox2,textbox3)); //something like this method.
```

this is my sample code:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    clearThis();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `List<T>` constructor and [collection initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
clearThis(new List<TextBox>() { textbox1, textbox2, textbox3 });
```

You can also change your method to take `TextBox[]` array, and mark it using [`params` modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx):

```
public void clearThis(params TextBox[] txtbox){
    foreach (TextBox nTxtbox in txtbox){
        nTxtbox.Text = "";
    }
}
```

After that, you'll be able to call it like this:

```
clearThis(textbox1, textbox2, textbox3);
```

Comment: thanks pal, this solves my problem i can specify which textbox i want to clear thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would change the signature to accept `IEnumerable<TextBox>` instead of `List<TextBox>`.  The only thing you do is enumerate the argument, so the only capabilities you need are those of an enumerable.  This will allow you to pass any sequence of `TextBox` objects, not just lists.

Second, we have to figure out which text boxes you need.  If you already know which you want, then you can simply put them into a `TextBox[]` (which is an enumerable):

```
clearThis(new TextBox[] { txtOne, txtTwo, txtThree });
```

Or, you could pass in some other enumerable, such as:

```
clearThis(Controls.OfType<TextBox>());
```

(Note that this will do a shallow search.  To perform a deep search, consider using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4630450/501250) that I wrote for another answer.  Then you could simply do `clearThis(GetControlsOfType<TextBox>(this))`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear TextBoxes on a Form, you could use this method,

```
void ClearAllText(Control formTest)
{
    foreach (Control c in formTest.Controls)
    {
      if (c is TextBox)
         ((TextBox)c).Clear();
      else
         ClearAllText(c);
    }
}
```