# How can I print the contents of a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, printdialog

I found code [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e115cf3b-a6ee-48f3-9cab-f6ad8f6ff3b5/how-to-print-contents-of-webbrowser?forum=wpf) that I used like so:

```
printDialog1.PrintDocument
(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)webBrowserMap.Document).DocumentPaginator, "Alchemy Map");
```

...but with that I get two err msgs, namely:

```
0)'System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog' does not contain a definition for 'PrintDocument' and no extension method 'PrintDocument' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

1) The type or namespace name 'IDocumentPaginatorSource' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I then tried to adapt the code from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60179/Web-Browser-in-C) this way:

```
private void buttonPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser wb = getCurrentBrowser();
    wb.ShowPrintDialog();
}

private WebBrowser getCurrentBrowser()
{
    return (WebBrowser)tabControlAlchemyMaps.SelectedTab.Controls[0];
}
```

...but got, "*System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser'.*

I then tried to derive from what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630391/get-all-controls-of-a-specific-type), with this code:

```
private void buttonPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser web = getCurrentBrowser();
    web.ShowPrintDialog();
}

private WebBrowser getCurrentBrowser()
{
    // I know there's a better way, because there is only one WebBrowser control on the tab
    foreach (var wb in tabControlAlchemyMaps.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<WebBrowser>())
    {
        return wb;
    }
    return null;
}
```

...and, although I can step through it, and it seems to work (I get to the "web.ShowPrintDialog()" line with no err msg), I see no print dialog. So how *can* I go about printing the contents of a WebBrowser control?

Comment: All of it? If so, what is the Winforms way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN page about printing windows forms web browser control:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0wes9a3(v=vs.90).aspx

```
private void PrintHelpPage()
{
    // Create a WebBrowser instance. 
    WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();

    // Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
    webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

    // Set the Url property to load the document.
    webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(@"\\myshare\help.html");
}

private void PrintDocument(object sender,
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

    // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Since I don't need to dynamically create a WebBrowser, and the document will already be loaded when the user mashes the Print button, it seems I could get by with a simple webBrowser.Print();