# How to shorten control properties

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox

In my code I change properties of items very often - almost 100 times in one void. These are the most common: `checkBox.Enabled = true` and `checkBox.Checked = true`.

I need my application to have a small file size, so I want to be able to type `checkBox.E(t)` to total an 11 byte saving (minus the initial declaration of `*.E` and `bool t = true`.

Is there a way to shorten access to these properties like I have shown above?
This also means that `checkBox.E()` would have return `true` or `false` as the property is actually set?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with _shorten_? Technically these are properties not functions.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, something like that.

Comment: @Steve I changed the question. I thought function was the wrong thing.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to change a perfectly understandable property name to something that requires an effort to understand what's going on? Do you have some background on C++ macros with #define?

Comment: @Steve No, I don't know C++. Understandability is less important for me than file size. I'm the only one who will view this code.

Comment: No, I really cannot understand your requirement. E() instead of Enabled saves 4 bytes and are four SOURCE bytes, not on the compiled executable.

Comment: So i guess you will change the variable name `checkBox` to `cb` as well ?

Comment: @Steve I use `Enabled` about 100 times. That means 400 bytes total. If I do the same with other properties, I could probably save approx. 500 KB

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Yep, I've made the names small enough to distinguish them, but not long enough to be 25 chars each

Comment: If you use the same code in a hundred places then extract a pattern from that and apply that. Don't go around changing well-readable member names to gibberish.

Comment: Why are 500 kb so important to you?

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not sure to how get a pattern. I set every checkbox on my form to checked and disable it.

Comment: Yeah, so, put them in a list and use `foreach (var checkBox in checBoxList) { checkBox.Enabled = true; }`? [Or even `foreach (var checkBox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) { ... }`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630391/get-all-controls-of-a-specific-type)? Plenty of solutions, depending on what your code is actually supposed to do.

Comment: Here is a very simple solution for the problem (Written abbreviated to save space): Y c s s t p o t p y w t c b g t t b a. T a s t p t a, i y w t s t. O t o h, i m n b s a g i!

Comment: @NineBerry Good point, but its nothing like that. I would have a key telling me what letter equals what word. It's like: T i m w o d th. T=This; i=is; m=my; w=way; o=of; d=doing; th=things;

Comment: Edited and voting to reopen, because OP supplied enough clarifications to make the question entirely unambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to make a shortcut for setting a property on a specific type, you can do it with an extension method inside a static class:

```
public static class CheckBoxExtensions {
    public static void E(this CheckBox cb) {
        cb.Enabled = true;
    }
    public static void C(this CheckBox cb) {
        cb.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Now you can write `checkbox.E()` instead of `checkbox.Enabled = true`.

You should be very careful with extensions like that, because they have a great potential of transforming a perfectly readable code into something only its author would have a chance of understanding.

Comment: I tried using this, but it said it was unavailable due to its protection level.

Comment: @DavidWheatley I was missing `public` in the code.

Comment: What about if I wanted to set the `Enabled` property of a checkbox?

Comment: @DavidWheatley Add a second parameter of type `bool`, and assign it to `cb.Enabled` instead of the constant `true`. The call will look like this: `check.E(true)`.

Comment: Would that be: `public static bool E(this CheckBox cb) {cb.enabled;}`?

Comment: @DavidWheatley `public static bool E(this CheckBox cb, bool e) {cb.Enabled = e;}`

Comment: When I do that, I get the error: `'CheckBoxExtensions.e(CheckBox, bool)': not all code paths return a value`

Comment: @DavidWheatley Sorry, it should be void: `public static void E(this CheckBox cb, bool e) {cb.Enabled = e;}`