# c# panel array simplify code

Tags: c#, arrays, panel, simplify

I want to simplify this code. The Code should put all panels (panel1 - panel10) into an panel array

A solution could be with a for loop, but I don't know how to increase the panelname:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Panel[] arr = new Panel[10];

        int i = 0;
        arr[i] = panel1;
        arr[i++] = panel2;
        arr[i++] = panel3;
        arr[i++] = panel4;
        arr[i++] = panel5;
        arr[i++] = panel6;
        arr[i++] = panel7;
        arr[i++] = panel8;
        arr[i++] = panel9;
        arr[i++] = panel10;
    }
```

Comment: FYI `i++` is a post-increment so the first `arr[i++]` is equivalent to `arr[0]`

Comment: To mention: It's a WindowsFormsApplication and on Form1.cs I created 10 panels (like button, textbox etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all controls of a specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630391/get-all-controls-of-a-specific-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `panel1..panel10` are directly on the form you can try *Linq*:

```
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 public Form1() {
   InitializeComponent();

   // If you want all the panels, remove (comment out) "Where"
   Panel[] arr = Controls
    .OfType<Panel>()
    .Where(panel => Regex.IsMatch(panel.Name, "^panel([0-9]|(10))$"))
    .ToArray();
 }
```

**Edit:** If you have, say, `42` panels the only thing you have to change is the filter `Where`:

```
 public Form1() {
   InitializeComponent();

   Panel[] arr = Controls
     .OfType<Panel>()
     .Where(panel => {
        // Given a panel you have to decide should you add it to array or not
        var match = Regex.Match(panel.Name, "^panel(?<num>[0-9]+)$");

        return match.Success &&
               int.Parse(match.Groups["num"].Value) >= 0 &&
               int.Parse(match.Groups["num"].Value) <= 42; })
     .ToArray();
 }
```

In case you want to organize all the panels with `Name` like `panelNumber` (e.g. `panel2`, `panel17`, `panel347`...) you can simplify the `Where` into

```
 .Where(panel => Regex.IsMatch(panel.Name, "^panel[0-9]+$"))
```

Comment: Thanks :) That helped me!

Comment: Can you edit this code to if I had 42 panels instead of 10?

Comment: @Pascal Niederberger: the only thing you have to edit is the filter `Where` - *which* panels you want to organize into the array.

Answer (score 4):

```
Panel[] panel = new Panel [] 
{
    panel1,
    panel2,
    panel3,
    ...
    panel10,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the array with contents like this:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Panel[] arr = new Panel[]{
        panel1,
        panel2,
        panel3,
        panel4,
        panel5,
        panel6,
        panel7,
        panel8,
        panel9,
        panel10
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An other solution is to use reflection like:

```
Panel[] arr = new Panel[10];
const string PanelName = "panel";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    FieldInfo pi = GetType().GetField(PanelName + (i + 1),
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    arr[i] = ((Panel)pi.GetValue(this));
}
```

Note that this is just an example. If a panel is not available this code will crash due to a `null` returned. If this could be possible, you need to improve the code a little bit.

Comment: Please, add `using System.Reflection;`

Comment: you need to start from 1 and not from 0

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Linq? Assuming all the panels are in the form.

```
var panelArr = Controls.OfType<Panel>(); //Filtering based on Type
panelArr.Where(p=> Regex.IsMatch(p.Name, "^panel([0-9]|(10))$")) //Filtering based on Panel Name
panelArr.ToArray(); //Fianlly into Array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set name `panel.Name = "pnl" + i.ToString();`

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Panel[] arr = new Panel[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.Name = "pnl" + i.ToString();
        arr[i] = panel;
    }
}
```