# Select all combo boxes on winform by LINQ

Tags: winforms, linq

I have 10 combo boxes in a tab control on a form. I want to select all on form load event as follows-

```
var comboBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().ToList();
```

But it selects only one. Any help?

Comment: Are they nested in sub-containers? [Get all controls of a specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4630391/669576)

Comment: Yes, those are in a tab control on two different tab pages.

Comment: You will need a recursive solution, which is basically answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4630450/1789202)