# How do I change the background colour of a form of a GUI program for 3 seconds in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, time, background-color

I'm writing a quiz game in C#. If the user guessed correctly, the background colour of the GUI form must change to green for 3 seconds and if the user guessed incorrectly, the background colour of the GUI form must change to red for 3 seconds. After 3 seconds the background colour of the GUI form must change back to white. However, the background colour of the form does not change at all while the program pauses for 3 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
private void KontroleerAntwoord()
{
    if (keuse == vrae[ranNum].Antwoord)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Green;

        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            if (c is RadioButton)
                ((RadioButton)c).BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Red;

        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            if (c is RadioButton)
            {
                if (((RadioButton)c).Text == vrae[ranNum].Antwoord)
                    c.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                else
                    c.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
    }

    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: You are `Sleep`ing on the UI thread (which effectively blocks its updates). Instead you can use a timer.

Comment: The UI can't be painted as you have send the Thread to sleep. Call Refresh() before.

Comment: You can reduce your code by using [Controls.OfType<>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4630442/2330053) and passing in `RadioButton`...

Answer (score 1):

You should never use `Thread.Sleep();` on the UI thread. This will "block" the thread and prevent it from doing anything else, such as updating the UI.

The easy workaround is to use `await Task.Delay(...)` instead.

```
private async Task KontroleerAntwoord()
{
    // Set color to red
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    // Set color to white
}
```

This will use a timer internally so that the UI thread is never blocked. Please note that this can lead to odd behavior if you run this method multiple times within the 3s delay. So you might want to do something like incrementing a member variable before the delay, and decementing it after the delay, and only reset the color if the variable is zero.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call `Sleep()` on the UI thread.
This will not allow any UI events to be handled and make it unresponsive.
It is **bad practice** in general, and specifically in your case will not allow to handle a UI refresh event.

Instead you should perform the waiting asynchronously.

One way would be to use a **timer**, as shown below.

```
Color orgBackColor = Color.Empty; // add this data member

void MyActionOnUIThread()
{
    if (this.orgBackColor != Color.Empty)
    {
         return; // we are during a previous operation
    }

    // Keep the current color and change it:
    this.orgBackColor = this.BackColor;
    this.BackColor = Color.Green;

    // Use a timer to restore the color after 3 seconds:
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 3000;
    timer.Tick +=
        (object obj, EventArgs args) =>
        {
            this.BackColor = orgBackColor;
            this.orgBackColor = Color.Empty; // for next time
            timer.Stop();
        };
    timer.Start()
}
```

Some notes:

1. The original `BackColor` is stored in a data member and used to restore the color after the delay.
2. The code protects against executing the operation before the previous one completed.