# How to keep text on the screen a certain amount of time?

Tags: c#, user-interface, time

I'm writing a quiz game in C# where I use five questions from an array of 20 questions. For each question, I want the question with four possible answers to appear on the screen and let the user choose an option. If the user guesses correctly the screen must be green for 3 seconds, otherwise red for 3 seconds and then show the next question or return to the home screen. However, if I guess the answer, the program goes immediately to the next question and then the screen is green or red for 3 seconds. When I guess the answer for the last question, my program goes immediately back to the home screen without changing the colour of the screen.

Here is my code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Speletjie
{
    public partial class frmVrae : Form
    {
         Color agtergrond = Color.Empty;

         public frmVrae()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void frmVrae_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             Toets.Tel = 0;

             VertoonVraag();
         }

         private void btnDienIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             KryAntwoord();
             KontroleerAntwoord();
             Toets.MaakLysKorter();

             if (Toets.Tel < 5)
                 VertoonVraag();
             else
             {
                 frmSpeletjie speletjie = new frmSpeletjie();

                 this.Hide();
                 speletjie.Show();
             }
         }

         private void VertoonVraag()
         {
             lblVraag.Text = Toets.Vrae[Toets.RanNum].Vraag;
             rdbKeuse1.Text = Toets.Vrae[Toets.RanNum].Keuses[0];
             rdbKeuse2.Text = Toets.Vrae[Toets.RanNum].Keuses[1];
             rdbKeuse3.Text = Toets.Vrae[Toets.RanNum].Keuses[2];
             rdbKeuse4.Text = Toets.Vrae[Toets.RanNum].Keuses[3];
             ++Toets.Tel;
         }

         private void KryAntwoord()
         {
             foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                 if (c is RadioButton)
                     if (((RadioButton)c).Checked)
                         Toets.Keuse = c.Text;
         }

         private void KontroleerAntwoord()
         {
             System.Windows.Forms.Timer tydhouer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

             if (agtergrond != Color.Empty)
                 return;

             this.agtergrond = this.BackColor;

             if (Toets.Keuse == Toets.Vrae[Toets.RanNum].Antwoord)
             {
                 this.BackColor = Color.Green;

                 foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                     if (c is RadioButton)
                         ((RadioButton)c).BackColor = Color.Green;
             }
             else
             {
                 this.BackColor = Color.Red;

                 foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                     if (c is RadioButton)
                     {
                         if (((RadioButton)c).Text == Toets.Vrae[Toets.RanNum].Antwoord)
                             c.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                         else
                             c.BackColor = Color.Red;
                     }
            }

            tydhouer.Interval = 3000;

            tydhouer.Tick += (object obj, EventArgs args) =>
            {
                this.BackColor = agtergrond;

                foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                    if (c is RadioButton)
                        c.BackColor = agtergrond;

                this.agtergrond = Color.Empty;

                tydhouer.Stop();
            };

            tydhouer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Try to get used to naming variables in english. English is the language of code, and makes your code much more easily understood worldwide!

Comment: Also, this is the third time you are asking pretty much the same question, please don't do that! It is better to edit your previous questions. [3 monts ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77288870/how-do-i-keep-text-on-the-screen-for-a-certain-amount-of-time), [4 days before that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77258364/how-do-i-change-the-background-colour-of-a-form-of-a-gui-program-for-3-seconds-i)

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple solution is to use [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-8.0):

```
private async void SubmittAnswerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try{
    if( IsCorrectAnswer()){
          SetBackground(Colors.Green);             
    }
    else{
          SetBackground(Colors.Red);
    }
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    SetBackground(Colors.Gray);
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    // handle failure
  }
}
```

The Task.Delay is essentially a wrapper around a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-8.0), and async/await uses the compiler to help build a state machine. But you need to be somewhat careful with code like this, since you need to to consider things like what will happen if the user submits the same answer twice within a second.

You can deal with this by doing things like disabling the submit button. But in some cases it may be clearer to write an explicit state machine, with a timer that transitions between states.